# Show a view on every view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have to show a view on the current view controller that is being displayed on recieving a push notification. I want that i make one view that can add up as plugin to my current view controller, so that despite of adding the same view to every view controller. i just add to it the currently displayed view controller.

please help me with this.

Also, the view contains some buttons - so where should i add the button actions.

Comment: add your `UIView` in a BaseViewController and all your others viewController should subclass that one, this will let you show your view in any viewController

Comment: Add the view on to Container View Controller(UINavigationController, UITabBarController) of your Application, it will displayed in complete application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an extension of `UIViewController`. Something like this.

```
extension UIViewController {    
    func showNotificationView() {
        let notiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        notiView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
        notiView.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(notiView)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callbackButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        notiView.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func callbackButton(_ sender:Any) {
        // button callback
    }
}
```

Comment: well, the function was called but the view didnot display on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you present the ViewController on window to show push. On window we don't need to care about the currently visible controller.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of the way to achieve this.